# If string appears 10 times run function on the 10th

Tags: php

I'm getting a string from a file using php's get_Contents() function.

However, before continuing on with what needs to be done, I need to find if there are 10 instances of a string, in this case `<item>` and then run a function for that specific section.

I am thinking the following will be possible after getting the last one:

```
$str_itemOpen = /* get 10th <item> in list */
$str_itemClose = /* get 10th </item> in list */
$str = $str_itemOpen . $str_itemClose
$removed_last = preg_replace(/'.'/, '', $str);
```

I am not 100% certain that would work, but essentially it is going to get the 10th occurrence of `<item>` and `</item>` in the file, if they exist, and then remove the tags and everything in them.

Comment: Seeing the string could be useful. If it is XML/HTML, you can obtain better results using a Parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will get all positions of the `<item>` and `</item>`

```
$needle = "<item>";
$lastPos = 0;
$positionsItemOpen = array();

while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positionsItemOpen[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

$needle = "</item>";
$lastPos = 0;
$positionsItemClose = array();

while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $positionsItemClose[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}
```

Then you can check if there are 10 of them:

```
if (count($positionsItemOpen) >= 10) 
{
    //there are at least 10 instances, so you can work with it

    //do the manipulations with string
    $itemLength = $positionsItemClose[9] - $positionsItemOpen[9];
    $itemStr = substr($str, $positionsItemOpen[9], $itemLength);
    $removed_last = preg_replace(/'.'/, '', $str);
}
```